# Batch append to end of a file name before the extension with ren command

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I would like to rename all files in a folder, which have different extensions, to have their file name end with "`_1`" while preserving the existing extensions.

I tried `ren * *_1*`, which just replaced the last instance of an already-existing underscore in the same to be `_1`. I also tried `ren * *_1.*`, but this added `_1` to the end of file names.

I'm using the command line (typing cmd from the folder search bar) in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop to iterate each file in a directory and specify the [variable substitutions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) individually to get the name of the file minus the extension and the file extension plus the preceding dot. You can use those and add in the `_1` string to get the expected output per each file iterated.

> **Essentially this. . .**
>
> - Iterates all `*.*` files in a specific directory (not recursively)
> - Uses [variable substitutions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for getting ***the file name without the extension*** and ***the file extension*** *separately/individually*
> - Concatenates ***the file name with no extension*** to ***the `_1` string*** to ***the original "." extension*** and passes that per file as the second argument to the [ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command.

---

**Command Line**

```
for %a in ("C:\path\*.*") do ren "%~a" "%~Na_1%~Xa"
```

**Batch Script**

```
SET "Src=C:\path"
SET "Str=_1"
for %%a in ("%Src%\*.*") do ren "%%~a" "%%~Na%Str%%%~Xa"
```

---

### Further Resources

[FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

- **Variable Substitutions (FOR /?)**

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > ```
- [Ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
- [Variable Substitutions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
SET "Str=_1"
for %%a in (".\*.*") do ren "%%~a" "%%~Na%Str%%%~Xa"
```

to rename all the files in the same directory as the batch file.
You can also change ren to copy, to copy and rename files.